# node.js is the function on the server side when drawing lines to connect users' point?

Tags: node.js

I want every user to have a point representing their mouse, then ask the canvas to draw lines between users' points.

So i wonder if the drawing lines function is on the sever's side? Then how to write the Eventemitter?

I'm a beginner, so...please give detail if possible.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Think of node.js as server-side technology, and your client-side approach would basically the same if you used Ruby, or Java, PHP, etc.

Drawing is client-side only, and you'd use something like canvas tag and API in client-side JS.

Hope this helps.

Oh and to your point about each user's mouse, what the node.js server would be responsible for is receiving the location from each user, and then sending these points to the clients.  When each client receives these point updates, you redraw the canvas, etc in local javascript (again, not node js).   This sounds like a good use-case for [socket.io](http://socket.io/) (based on WebSockets)

Comment: thx. May i also ask how to generate animation on canvas and make sure all the users see the same thing?

Comment: Hard to answer specifically, but here is a start: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

Comment: no but I mean i know how to generate, but don't know how I can make sure all the users see the same thing on the canvas, socket.io?

Comment: I'll send you some info out of S.O.